# OTP not getting reset in react-otp-input

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using below code for otp, when i click on resend Otp, the otp doesnt get cleared. Can you please help on what i am missing.

I have referred below working code as well but still it doesnt work.
https://github.com/devfolioco/react-otp-input/blob/main/src/demo/index.jsx

i have tried a lot but still it doesnt work.

```
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import React, { Component, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import OtpInput from 'react-otp-input';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import walletClientX from "../../../utils/api/walletClientX";
import { FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";

class VerifyOTP extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      otp: '1',
      numInputs: 6,
      separator: '',
      isDisabled: false,
      hasErrored: false,
      isInputNum: false,
      isInputSecure: false,
      minLength: 0,
      maxLength: 40,
      placeholder: '',
    };
  }

  
  handleOtpChange = (otp) => {
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
      if (otp === '' || re.test(otp)) {
        this.setState({ otp });
      }
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleNumInputsChange = (e) => {
    let numInputs = e.target.value;
    const { minLength, maxLength } = this.state;

    if (numInputs < minLength || numInputs > maxLength) {
      numInputs = 4;

      console.error(`Please enter a value between ${minLength} and ${maxLength}`);
    }

    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: parseInt(numInputs, 10) });
  };

  clearOtp = () => {
    this.setState({ otp: '' });
  };

  handleCheck = (e) => {
    const { name } = e.target;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ [name]: !prevState[name] }));
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.state.otp);
  };

  goBack = () => {
   
    this.props.onCloseVerifyOTPModal(false);
  };

  resendOtp = () => {
    
    this.clearOtp();
  };
  submitWithdrawRequest = () => {

    
    this.props.onVerifyOTP(this.state.otp);
  };


  render() {
    const {
      otp,
      numInputs,
      separator,
      isDisabled,
      hasErrored,
      isInputNum,
      isInputSecure,
      minLength,
      maxLength,
      placeholder,
    } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <Modal show onHide={this.props.onCloseVerifyOTPModal}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton className="border-0">
          <Modal.Title>
            <strong>
              <FormattedMessage
                id="wallet.otp-verification"
                defaultMessage="OTP Verification"
              />
            </strong>
          </Modal.Title>

        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body className="text-center font-proxima-nova">
          <p className="text-center otp-text"> Enter the OTP sent to registered mobile number.</p>

          <OtpInput 
            inputClassName="otpInput"
            numInputs={numInputs}
            isDisabled={isDisabled}
            hasErrored={hasErrored}
            errorStyle="error"
            onChange={this.handleOtpChange}
            separator={<span>{separator}</span>}
            isInputNum={isInputNum}
            isInputSecure={isInputSecure}
            shouldAutoFocus
            value={otp}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            inputStyle={{
              width: "3rem",
              height: "3rem",
              margin: "0 1rem",
              fontSize: "2rem",
              borderRadius: 0,
              borderWidth: 0,
              borderBottomColor: '#203BCF',
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
            }}
          />
          <p></p>
          <p className="text-center otp-text">Didn’t receive the OTP ? &nbsp;
            <a href="#" className="resendOtp"
              onClick={this.resendOtp} >Resend OTP</a></p>


          <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary home-btn mt-4"
                onClick={this.submitWithdrawRequest}
              >
                <FormattedMessage
                  id="wallet.verify-submit"
                  defaultMessage="VERIFY & SUBMIT"
                />
              </button>

              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary home-btn mt-4"
                onClick={this.goBack}
              >
                <FormattedMessage id="general.back" defaultMessage="Back" />
              </button>
            </div>


          </div>


        </Modal.Body>

      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
export default VerifyOTP;
```